# Each row has a population, but I want a random individual

Tags: r, sample, weighted, population

Suppose I have data structured like this:

```
      country population
1 Afghanistan   30000000
2      Brazil  200000000
3    Cameroon   22250000
```

There are a total of 252.2 million people represented here. Suppose I want to pick one individual at random:

`i <- sample (1:sum(df$population))`

then report her country. How do I find the country row corresponding to individual i? I know the rule of thumb is that iteration through a data frame means you're doing something wrong, but (aside from creating a new list with one row per individual, which sounds terrible) I can't think of a good way to figure out where individual i falls within the population.

Comment: You can sample the row i.e. `indx <- sample(nrow(df1),1)` and use that as index to subset the row. i..e  `df1[indx, ]`

Comment: you can specify weights to `sample()`, ie `with(mydata, sample(country,1,prob=population))`

Comment: @akrun: I believe that gives me one of the rows of my dataframe sampled with equal probability, which is not equivalent to selecting one of the individuals with equal probability.

Comment: That's what MrFlick's suggestion does. It makes the probability of sampling a country proportional to it's population.

Comment: Indeed. If MrFlick's were formatted as an answer, I'd give him the check mark to properly credit him, but instead I've marked your extended version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by MrFlick in the comments, you can sample the country with the probability given by the country's population.

```
> pops <- read.table(text="country population
1 Afghanistan   30000000
2      Brazil  200000000
3    Cameroon   22250000", header=T)

> sample(pops$country, 1, prob=pops$population)
```

As an example of how this will be proportional to the population, just do this a lot of times and the ratio between sampled is approximately the same as the ratio between the populations:

```
> set.seed(42)
> countries <- replicate(100000, sample(pops$country, 1, prob=pops$population))
> table(countries)/sum(table(countries))
countries
Afghanistan      Brazil    Cameroon 
0.12058     0.79052     0.08890 

> pops$population/sum(pops$population)
[1] 0.11892963 0.79286422 0.08820614
```

A different way of doing this would be calculating the cumulative sum of the populations, sampling from *world pop* and then identifying what's that person's country:

```
> pops$cumPop <- cumsum(pops$population)
> set.seed(42)
> person <- sample(1:pops$cumPop[nrow(pops)], 1)    
> pops$country[which(person <= pops$cumPop)[1]] #The country is the first with cumSum higher than the person ID.
[1] Cameroon
Levels: Afghanistan Brazil Cameroon
```

The first alternative is much simpler, but the second has the advantage of actually sampling "someone" in case you need to use that for something else than returnign a country.